# How to parse an XML element that has an attribute inside it ? Android ,Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, xmlpullparser

I have an XML file from server. I use xmlPullPrser for parsing it into Kotlin, but it has an 'id' attribute . I don't Know how to get the 'id' value. thank you in advance for your answer.
this is a part of my xml file :

````
```    
<videoList >
    <video id="843">
        <title></title>
        <author>Ghoneim</author> 
    </video>
    <video id="887">
        <title>Anatomic</title>
        <author>Tewari</author>
    </video>
</videoList>
```
````

this is some parts of my code for using XmlPullParser:

````
```
class VideoXmlParser {
@Throws(XmlPullParserException::class, IOException::class)
fun parse(inputStream: InputStream): List<Videos> {
    inputStream.use { inputStream ->
        val parser: XmlPullParser = Xml.newPullParser()
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false)
        parser.setInput(inputStream, null)
        parser.nextTag()
        return readVideoList(parser)
    }
}

}

@Throws(XmlPullParserException::class, IOException::class)
    fun readVideoList(parser: XmlPullParser): List<Videos> {
         val videos = mutableListOf<Videos>()
         parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "videoList")
         while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.eventType != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
              continue
    }

    // Starts by looking for the video tag
    if (parser.name == "video") {
        videos.add(readVideo(parser))
    } else {
        skip(parser)
    }
}
return videos

}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Once your `parser` is at the '*video*' tag you can use `parser.getAttributeValue`